# How to run AVD with Google Play in Gitlab CI?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have such ci config:

```
image: eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy
 
variables:
  # should match 'compileSdkVersion'
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"
  # should match 'buildToolsVersion'
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.3"
  # pick cli version from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html section 'CLI Tools Only'
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "6514223"
 
before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
 
  # setup Android home for moving/exporting the downloaded sdk into it
  - export ANDROID_HOME="${PWD}/android-home"
  - install -d $ANDROID_HOME
  # install official Android SDK tools from official source
  - wget --output-document=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - pushd $ANDROID_HOME
  - unzip -d cmdline-tools cmdline-tools.zip
  - popd
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/
 
  # setup gradle home directory
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=${PWD}/.gradle
 
  # setup Android SDK manager
  - sdkmanager --version
  - yes | sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --licenses || true
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platform-tools"
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
 
cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy



UI-Tests:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    # setup sdkmanager
    - sdkmanager --list | grep system-images
    - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --install "system-images;android-29;default;arm64-v8a"
    - echo y | sdkmanager  "emulator" >/dev/null
    - echo y | sdkmanager "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
    - echo y | avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
    - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window &
 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/reports/androidTests
      - app/build/outputs/androidTest-results
```

On the test stage I would like to run Espresso tests. For this purpose I installed AVD, but I got the error:

```
$ sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --install "system-images;android-29;default;arm64-v8a"
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... arm64-v8a/data/misc/
$ echo y | sdkmanager  "emulator" >/dev/null
$ echo y | sdkmanager "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... x86/VerifiedBootPara
$ echo y | avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86"
Auto-selecting single ABI x86
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no] 
 0: PlayStore: Does the device supports Google Play?
PlayStore.enabled [no]:offset 0, count -1, length 256
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I read that during manual running tests I need to enable this google play in config.ini file, but I'm not sure that it is the best way for CI. Maybe I selected the wrong AVD image?

Answer (score 1):

Two things, I think you have to repeatedly answer the interactive questions provided by `avdmanager create avd ...`. One way to do this is to use `yes` and the string to return. So,

```
... 
# preceding code
yes no | avdmanager create avd -f -n testAVD -k "system-images;android-$ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK;google_apis_playstore;x86"
# rest of code
...
```

and is the path to the emulator correctly referenced here `android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator`?

Comment: and it should install google play on the emulator in the end?

Comment: I think there are pre-packaged images that come with Google Play, it might be beneficial to use any of them instead.